# How to get options from html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-widget-factory

I am using jQueryUI Widget Factory and I am trying to retrieve the options that I set in the html file.

Here is the Widget Code (form.js):

```
(function ($, undefined) {

$.widget('ulti.uiForm', {

    //#region options
    options: {
        url: "",
        thankYou: true,//Enable thank you page
        thankYouPage:null,
        selector: 'form',
        posted: null, // Callback for ajax done method.
        //#region leadTemplate
        leadTemplate : {

        },
        //#endregion leadTemplate
    },
    //#endregion options

    _create: function () {
        this.element.addClass("ulti-uiForm");

    },

    _init: function () {

        // Load/copy lead template to element instance data...
        this.element.data('lead', this.options.leadTemplate);
        this._appendQSParms(this.element.data('lead'));

    },



    destroy: function () {
        // Restore element to pre-uiForm create state...
        this.element.removeClass('ulti-uiForm');
        this._destroy();

    },



    // Very basic diagnosic method to check that all minimum requirements are populated on the object.


    // TODO EXPOSE .done as a posted callback in options.
    post: function () {

        var $ajaxResult;
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: this.options.url,
            data: JSON.stringify(this.element.data('lead')),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            accept: "application/json",

            beforeSend: function () {

            }
        })
        // callback handler on success - populate lead object with returned data.
        .done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            self.element.data('lead', response);
            self._trigger("posted", self.element.data('lead'));


                if (options.thankYou === true) {

                   window.location.replace(options.thankYouPage);
                }

            })
        // callback handler that will be called on failure
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { //.fail(function () {
            // log the error to the console
            console.error("Error POSTing gateway object. Status:" + textStatus + " Error: " + errorThrown);
        })
        .always(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        });

        return self; // support chaining...
    },

    _setOption: function (key, value) {

    this._super(key, value);
}

});
})(jQuery);
```

The JS that is in the html:

```
    var uiForm;
    uiForm = $('#stepform').uiForm({
            options: {
                url: 'http://someurl.cloudapp.net/api/leads',
                thankYouPage:'thankyou.html',
            posted: function (evt) {


                //notEqual(uiForm.data('lead').SessionId, null, "Post operation succeeded lead sessionId: " + uiForm.data('lead').SessionId);
                //start();
            }
        }
    });


    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

        //post the form
        uiForm.uiForm('post');

    });
```

I'm just looking to send the thankYouPage option from the js in the html file to form.js and apply the option to the 'done' call back:

```
if (this.options.thankYou === true) {
    window.location.replace(options.thankYouPage);
}
```

Your insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your widget, pass in the `options` object.  In your code, you are passing the `options` object as a property on a parent object.  Don't use the parent object, just pass it in directly.

```
var uiForm = $('#stepform').uiForm({
    url: 'http://someurl.cloudapp.net/api/leads',
    thankYouPage:'thankyou.html',
    posted: function (evt) {
        //notEqual(uiForm.data('lead').SessionId, null, "Post operation succeeded lead sessionId: " + uiForm.data('lead').SessionId);
        //start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking here: "Send the thankYouPage option from the js in the html file to form.js and apply the option to the done callback"... If what I'm assuming you're trying to do is pull data out of your html, you have two ways:

1 - Pull the data out of a data-* attirbute such as

`<div id="ImSomeWhereInYourCode" data-star="SomeValue">*</div>`

and

```
var star = $("#ImSomeWhereInYourCode").attr("data-star");
// This will set star to "SomeValue"
```

2 - Append to the global scope directly on build of your page, and reference it later.

```
<script>
  window.star = "SomeValue";
  // ... Later ...
  .done(function () {
    var newVar = window.star;
    // newVar = "SomeValue"
  });
</script>
```